# How to extract a fixed number of frames starting from specific frame with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, decoding

I'm developing some GUI, which, among other things, implements video player with a step-by-step option. Using this option, I want to assign the start and end frames for the sequence which I want to extract (in a row YUV420 format) from a mkv file. I intended to use ffmpeg but I cannot find how I can assign the start frame with frame (not time) resolution. How can I do it with ffmpeg or another doftware?

Comment: Are you using the C API or the CLI tool?

Comment: I'm using Python, but probably I'll do it in C#

Comment: Are you using **ffmpeg** via its C API or the CLI tool?

Comment: C API, but if CLI tool can help me (and C API not) I'll use CLI.